# DB Paradox 3.5 and DOS on VMWare Player 4

Tags: usb, printer, vmware-player, ntvdm

My organization have to work with Paradox 3.5. We have 2 HD on a computer. One with Windows and one with DOS, where Paradox 3.5 is placed. So we bought a new printer, which does not work on LPT port. Maybe i'm stupid, but i cannot find a way to set up a new printer on DOS system through USB and to set up Paradox to use a printer, and in general it is too difficult to reboot a computer each time we need a Paradox.
I've created an disk image with Acronis and have created a virtual machine, whicn runs on Windows. DOS starts, works, but when i try to run Paradox, it says me:

```
System: No packet was sent

End of adaptation `Paradox 3.5 (total)`
Copyright (C) KOKOM, ParaGraph, vers. 3.5/02, 1991

Program modifier for BETA
Copyright (C) ParaGraph, Chi-sovt, v. 3.23 (21.06.91), 1990-1991
```

and returns to console.

What does it mean?

I cannot google anything about that message. I've found a lot of info about converting Paradox into newer version or into another DB, but i think it will take more time to get it work like before, than trying to find a solution to get it work with VMWare Player.

The main goal is to make printer work in Paradox program. I think the easiest way is virtualization (it is easy to connect USB printer to VMWare Player through "virtual" LPT)

Can anybody help me?